# MatLab: Corner Detection on Binary Image

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry, rounded-corners, matlab-cvst, corner-detection

I am trying to find a way to find the corner points on this binary image in MatLab

[image: Binary Image]

I have been trying to find a way to fit a triangle over this image and finding the vertices. I have tried finding corners but the values it returns are not always correct.
Is there any way I can sharpen the edges so that the corner function can return better results?

I appreciate any input! Thanks!

[image]

What strategy seems easier and more efficient? What existing MatLab functions could I use?

Comment: how many/what corners do you want to detect? can you add a picture with the corners outlined?

Comment: There should be 3 corners and I have added an attachment to the original question.

Comment: Does anyone know a way for me to detect the three corners? I've been looking into houghline but I am not that sure how to properly use it.

Comment: How have you been looking for the corners ? Please explain.

Comment: I was using the "corner" function in MatLab to get the best three corners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of image processing approach, let's try a more algebraic approach.

You have white pixels - 2D points on a plane, and you wish to find three half-planes (straight lines) that best separate these points from the rest of the plane.

So, let's start

```
img=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL2Cq.png'); %// read the image
bw = img(:,:,1) > 128;  %// convert to binary mask
[y x] = find(bw);  %// get the x-y coordinates of white pixels
n=numel(x);  %// how many do we have
```

For stability we subtract the mean of all points - centering the white pixels around the origin:

```
mm = mean([x y],1); 
mA = bsxfun(@minus, [x y], mm);
```

Now, a line can be described by two parameters, all the points `(x, y)` that satisfy `L(1)*x + L(2)*y = 1`. In order to find a line that all the points are strictly to one side of it, this inequality must hold for all points `(x,y)` of the set: `L(1)*x + L(2)*y <= 1`. We can force these inequalities and search for the most tight half plane `L` that fulfill this constraint using [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html):

```
L1 = quadprog(eye(2), -ones(2,1), mA, ones(n,1));
L2 = quadprog(eye(2), ones(2,1), mA, ones(n,1));
L3 = quadprog(eye(2), [1; -1], mA, ones(n,1));
```

Note how by changing the quadratic optimization target `f`, we are able to get different half planes separating the white pixels.

Once we have the three lines, we can get the intersection points (shifting them back from the origin by `mm`):

```
x12=inv([L1';L2'])*ones(2,1)+mm';
x23=inv([L3';L2'])*ones(2,1)+mm';
x13=inv([L3';L1'])*ones(2,1)+mm';
```

You can use see the results

```
imshow(bw,'border','tight'); 
hold all; 
%// plot the lines
ezplot(gca, @(x,y) L1(1)*(x-mm(1))+L1(2)*(y-mm(2))-1, [1 340 1 352]);
ezplot(gca, @(x,y) L2(1)*(x-mm(1))+L2(2)*(y-mm(2))-1, [1 340 1 352]);
ezplot(gca, @(x,y) L3(1)*(x-mm(1))+L3(2)*(y-mm(2))-1, [1 340 1 352]);
%// plot the intersection points
scatter([x12(1) x23(1) x13(1)],[x12(2) x23(2) x13(2)],50,'+r');
```

[image]

Comment: The code works great on some of the images I have, but it seems to run into some problems if I give it certain images like this one: http://imgur.com/qqg3cKS   Is there any way the fix this?

Comment: @user3315340 toying a bit with the `f` term in `quadprog` (the second argument) results with different solutions, for the image you sent `L3 = quadprog(eye(2), [-1; 1], mA, ones(n,1));` yields the desired solution.

Comment: @user1714410 why L1 the objective function is L(1)^2 + L(2)^2 - L(1)  - L(2)? The distance from "mean point" to the line?

Comment: I understand now, no need reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the minimum area circumscribed triangle.

First compute the convex hull of the blob.

Then try all distinct choices of three sides of the hull, extend the sides by computing the pairwise intersections and keep the triangle with the smallest positive area.

[image]